# how I get the preview product and next product in mysql?

Tags: mysql

how I get the preview product and next product in mysql?
for example: the current product is id 7 , I want to get 5 and 8 in table p , how to write the sql?

[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `p`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `p`;
CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `products_name` varchar(200) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of p
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('1', 'a');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('2', 'b');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('4', 'd');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('5', 'ed');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('11', 'f');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('7', 'gs');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('8', 'd');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('9', 'f');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT P1.id,
       P1.Products_Name
FROM P P1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT max(id)as ID FROM P WHERE id < 7
 UNION ALL
 SELECT min(id)as ID FROM P WHERE id > 7
)T ON T.ID = P1.ID
ORDER BY P1.ID ASC
```

[sqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61256/6/0)

Comment: hello, TinTran. +1 Great~!

Comment: thanks Jungsu Heo beginner's question but it's fun to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you could accomplish that using `HANDLER`, but this is not standard. BTW, what you want is difficult with only Standard SQL.

```
mysql> HANDLER p OPEN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> HANDLER p READ `PRIMARY` = (7);
+----+---------------+
| id | products_name |
+----+---------------+
|  7 | gs            |
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> HANDLER p READ `PRIMARY` NEXT;
+----+---------------+
| id | products_name |
+----+---------------+
|  8 | d             |
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  HANDLER p READ `PRIMARY` PREV LIMIT 1,1;
+----+---------------+
| id | products_name |
+----+---------------+
|  5 | ed            |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: I wan to get 5 and 8 in one sql, how to do ?